# Timediff in MySQL wrong values

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need some help with my PHP script.
I have a MySQL database, one of the columns contains datetime values for example:

2013-10-11 10:41:00

Now what I want is to set a condition to get for example all the values that are from the last 24 h, so I did this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  data
WHERE timediff(now(), myDate) < '24:00:00'
```

But for some reason, for example, right now it is 2013-10-11 20:46 and when I run this script, the values I get go all the way from 2013-10-01 10:47:00.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM  data
WHERE myDate >= now() - interval 24 hour
```

Answer (score 0):

TIMEDIFF returns a time value and comparisons with time values are problematic.

It is clearer and safer to change the time value into something that you can more easily test, such as seconds:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE time_to_sec(timediff(now(), myDate)) < 24 * 60 * 60;
```

That will work and it is clear what you are doing.